# Is it a bad practice to have two Angular controllers that shares same DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Imagine I have something like this:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    ...
    <body ng-controller="GlobalController">
        <div id="one">...</div>
        ...
        <div ng-controller="SpecificController" id="subPart">
            <div id="two">...</div>
            ...
        </div>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the controller `GlobalController` manages the whole body, while `SpecificController` only controls the `subPart`.

In that case, `div#one` can access to the `GlobalController`, but `div#two` is linked to `GlobalController` **and** `SpecificController`.

My question is to know if it's a bad practice to do that, because I imagine that having 2 controllers for the same DOM elements (such as `div#two`) can lead to conflicts...

Also, if it's not a bad practice, what should I take care in such situation? For example, I imagine that I have to be carefull to avoid having same properties in both controllers, right?

Thanks.

ps: I'm not sure if this question has been asked. I see several times the question "can I have the same controllers twice in the same page", but that's not my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing *wrong* with this in my opinion, you are just showing that there is an "inheritance" chain between your Controllers and it allows for more granular control over certain aspects of the DOM which may have nothing to do with the page as a whole.

You are correct about sharing properties, as the child controller will inherit its properties for the parent Controller:

```
function ParentCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.test = "One";
}

function ChildCtrl($scope) {
    console.log($scope.test); // Logs "One";
    $scope.test = "Two"; // We've re-defined the variable as "Two"
}
```

However, I would try to make it blindingly obvious in the code that `SpecificController` does indeed inherit from `GlobalController` in order to avoid collisions of data properties.

Comment: In fact, I have the feeling that my `div#two` cannot interact with a `$scope.foo` property that is on the `GlobalController`. I'm trying to create a JsFidlle to be sure, and I will edit my question...

Comment: Why should `SpecificController` inherit from `GlobalController` - it does not share that `div#one`?

Comment: @romaintaz `div#two` inherits any properties defined by `GlobalController` as it is nested - http://jsfiddle.net/Yu8ZW/

Answer (score 0):

I have often found that if you try to keep everything in a single controller, especially for large pages, then the size of your controllers can become unmanageable, so its actually my preference to use parent - child controller inheritance. Just keep in mind that when referring to parent properties from child DOM elements, you need to be cautious of you parent property naming strategy or use $parent.parentproperty in the child DOM when you need to refer.